# Achieve pitch on widestring with accent marks

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-6

I am developing some code (in Delphi 6) where I draw a widestring on a canvas. This works fine for the drawing itself.

However I would like to enable customer to have variable pitch. I do this currently by calculating a certain spacing and moving this step for each glyph. Works for most, but some scripts have accent marks that suddenly become separated. Illustration below : [image: Incorrect glyph pitch]

The top in illustration is my desired output. The disired is from pasting in MSWord, then adding spaces manually. The bottom in illustration is Word, adding letter spacing to a paragraph style.

Other software has same "simple way" of drawing, I tried InkScape as well.

Question is - can it be done using a Windows API ? Or is it a question of knowing which codepoints represent accent marks, then avoid space after these ? (the list should be [this one](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mn/list.htm) I guess) The last can of course be done, but is like a little "hack" in my book.

For reference, I use the "DrawTextW" function, similar to 
[example here](http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=175288)

My code for output:

```
for d := 1 to Textlength do
begin
  DrawTextW(
    bmp.Canvas.Handle,
    PWideChar(copy(TextW,d,1)),
    1,
    tmpArea,
    DT_SINGLELINE or DT_NOCLIP);

  // widest is width of widest char, for spacing
  //
  // this is where I could check if next is a nonspacing/combining
  // to avoid adding space.
  if dtoPitch in Options.Option then
    tmpArea.Left := tmpArea.Left + widest;
end;
```

Comment: You have to consider that unicode glyphs are arbitrarily multi-byte entities. [Combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) can't simply be rendered alone - it looks like you're treating each two-byte pair as a glyph.  With unicode this is not possible.  You have to parse the string to determine which bytes belong to the same glyph.

Comment: Without seeing your code we can only guess at what has happened. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @J... I think you come to the same conclusion I did.  Simply going over the code by each glyph, adding space,  is wrong, since some glyphs combine with the previous.

Comment: See also [Detecting and Retrieving codepoints and surrogates from a Delphi String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32020126/576719)